# Add stop words in Gensim

Tags: python, windows, nlp, gensim, stop-words

Thanks for stopping by!  I had a quick question about appending stop words. I have a select few words that show up in my data set and I was hopping I could add them to gensims stop word list.  I've seen a lot of examples using nltk and I was hoping there would be a way to do the same in gensim.  I'll post my code below:

```html
def preprocess(text):
    result = []
    for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
        if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and len(token) > 3:
            nltk.bigrams(token)
            result.append(lemmatize_stemming(token))
    return result
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While `gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS` is pre-defined for your convenience, and happens to be a `frozenset` so it can't be directly added-to, you could easily make a larger set that includes both those words and your additions. For example:

```py
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
my_stop_words = STOPWORDS.union(set(['mystopword1', 'mystopword2']))
```

Then use the new, larger `my_stop_words` in your subsequent stop-word-removal code. (The `simple_preprocess()` function of `gensim` doesn't automatically remove stop-words.)

Comment: Thanks, will this then work with the Gensim remove_stopwords() function?

Comment: No, as the `remove_stopwords()` function doesn't take any argument other than a (not-even-tokenized) string, and only uses the built-in, frozen set of stopwords. But you probably don't want to use `gensim.parsing.processing.remove_stopwords()` in most cases, especially if you have your own custom list of stop-words. It both splits-on-whitespace then rejoins your string, and most tokenization/preprocessing workflows will want to keep the text as a list-of-tokens for longer (or even through to the end of all training/analysis).

Comment: That function is only 2 lines – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/d5556ea2700333e07c8605385def94dd96fb2c94/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.py#L71 - and once you're using a custom set of stopwords & possibly other custom steps, you'll want to control the split & token-filtering, and possibly other token-canonicalization (if you're doing things like stemming or lemmatization), yourself in your own explicit code.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a custom function to my script. So far the results from Gensim's remove_stopwords() look good for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```html
def preprocess(text):
    result = []
    for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
        newStopWords = ['stopword1','stopword2']
        if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and token not in newStopWords and len(token) > 3:
            nltk.bigrams(token)
            result.append(lemmatize_stemming(token))
    return result
```

Comment: Doing two `not in` tests (`token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and token not in newStopWords`) with the second being against a `list` (which requires a linear probe) will be less efficient than creating your own superset of all your stop-words, as described in my answer, and then doing a single `not in` test against that. (Membership `in` tests for `set` are most efficient, and generally don't become less-efficient against larger sets – but multiple tests, or probes against lists, will slow as more `and`s or list-entries are added.)